# Dcount in unbound textbox

Tags: vba, database

```
=DCount("*","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159]) AND ([Type of Application] = 'New Transaction' ")
```

This is my expression on unbound textbox

What i am expecting is count all record on `tblMainDBASE` with date of payment is equal to text159 and type of application is equal to New Transaction

Comment: Why does this have a `php` tag?

Comment: Im sorry sir. my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the concatenating:

```
=DCount("*","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159] & " AND [Type of Application] = 'New Transaction'")
```

For pluralis as well:

```
=DCount("*","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159] & " AND ([Type of Application] = 'New Transaction' Or [Type of Application] = 'New Transactions')")
```

Comment: Woah.  this really helps me alot. thank you sir.
How about type of application is equal to 'New Transaction' or  New Transactions? Sometimes the encoder gets error on typing. and i cant count the new transactions.

Thank you

Comment: =DCount("*","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159] & " AND [Type of Application] = 'New Transaction' Or 'New Transactions'")

is this write @Gustav

Comment: You are close. See extended answer, please.